# calculate bearing between two polylines

Tags: math, geolocation, geospatial

I got two routes as polylines as lists of coordinates such as:
[13.072624,52.333508,13.763972,52.679616]
[52.679616,13.763972,52.333508,13.072624]

I need to compare the direction of two polylines. To do so I thought to get the angle between them and return true (going in the same direction) if it is smaller 45°.

[example of route comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDczR.png)

How can we do so?

Comment: It's *very* easy to get the acute angle between them, but *much* harder to compute the relative bearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to compare against each other is the unit vectors of the line segments. I don't know what language you are working in or how the lists are organized but the following pseudo code will get you the bearings.

```
// create end points of the line segments from lists
point0(x0, y0);
point1(x1, y1);
point2(x2, y2);
point3(x3, y3);

// create direction vectors from points
directionA = point1 - point0;
directionB = point3 - point2;

// normalize the direction vectors to have a length of 1
// assuming they are not degenerate
directionA.unitize();
directionB.unitize();

// get the dot product of the two direction vectors
dot = directionA.dot(directionB);

// Because the direction vectors are both unit length
// the dot product will return a value between -1.0 and 1.0
// The arc cosine will give you your angle between 0 and 180
angle = arc_cosine_degree(dot)
```

Then compare the angle to what ever tolerance you choose for determining "same" direction. Wikipedia has good explanations of each of the concepts that I use in the pseudo code (i.e. unit vector, dot product, arc cosine).

Good luck! GCB